# Webapp development tools for Blackberry

Tags: html, ide, blackberry, editor, web-applications

I am looking for a good Environment (GUI based Editor) for blackberry webapps.
e.g., is there a Eclipse plugin out there ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, and experience, using a GUI based editor for any kind of web development is a Very Bad Idea. Get to know HTML and CSS, write your own JavaScript. There isn't a [WYSIWYG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) editor out there that can generate markup as good as I can by hand.

Of course, the part were tools come in is testing. And getting to know the paricular inconsistencies of your platform. In that instance, check out:

- [BlackBerry Browser Development](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/browserdev/)

You'll also want to test, test and test. For that, grab yourself the full range of [BlackBerry emulators](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/resources/simulators.jsp).

Answer (score 1):

From my experience it seems that many BlackBerries have CSS and JS turned off by default, and quality of CSS and JS support (before 4.6 software) is just appalling.

You're stuck with very basic HTML forms and linear layout. There's nothing that visual editors can do with this.

Answer (score -1):

The Blackberry Applications are developed in Java and RIM provides the needed tools and simulators here: http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/resources/devtools.jsp